# How to print the first ten elements from Counter?

Tags: python, counter

With this code, I print all the elements sorted with the most common word used in the textfile first. How do I print only the first ten elements?

```
with open("something.txt") as f:
    words = Counter(f.read().split())
print(words)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the docs:

> most_common([n])
>
> Return a list of the n most common elements and their counts from the most common to the least. If n is omitted or None, most_common() returns all elements in the counter. Elements with equal counts are ordered arbitrarily:

I would try:

```
words = Counter(f.read().split()).most_common(10)
```

Source: [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common)

Answer (score 3):

This will give you the [most common](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) ten words in your `words` `Counter`:

```
first_ten_words = [word for word,cnt in words.most_common(10)]
```

You'll need to extract only first elements from the list of pairs `(word, count)` returned by [`Counter.most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common):

```
>>> words.most_common(10)
[('qui', 4),
 ('quia', 4),
 ('ut', 3),
 ('eum', 2),
 ('aut', 2),
 ('vel', 2),
 ('sed', 2),
 ('et', 2),
 ('voluptas', 2),
 ('enim', 2)]
```

with a simple list comprehension:

```
>>> [word for word,cnt in words.most_common(10)]
['qui', 'quia', 'ut', 'eum', 'aut', 'vel', 'sed', 'et', 'voluptas', 'enim']
```